# Heroes of Newerth on 15.04

Tags: 15.04, games

i tried to run this game on Kubuntu 15.04 (i used to play it two years back) but i cant seem to do that.

When i try to ./hon-x86_64 it spits this error:

```
./hon-x86_64: /home/aiphee/HoN/libs-x86_64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.52)
```

When I try to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH, it writes this:

```
warning: The VAD has been replaced by a hack pending a complete rewrite
K2 - Fatal Error: PNG header and library versions do not match
```

I installed `libpng14` with alien, any ideas?

EDIT:

Output:

```
aiphee@aiphee-MS-7596:~$ strings /home/aiphee/HoN/libs-x86_64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep CXXABI

CXXABI_1.3
CXXABI_1.3.1
CXXABI_1.3.2
CXXABI_1.3.3
CXXABI_1.3.4
CXXABI_1.3.5
CXXABI_1.3.6
CXXABI_TM_1
```

Comment: @A.B. The command's `strings`, not `string`.

Comment: @the_Seppi ups, sorry

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of: `strings /home/aiphee/HoN/libs-x86_64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep CXXABI`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The library `libstdc++.so.6` in Ubuntu 15.04 has `CXXABI_1.3.8`:

```
% strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep CXXABI_1.3.8
CXXABI_1.3.8
```

- Make the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` changes reversed.
- Make a backup of your `libstdc++.so.6` in `/home/aiphee/HoN/libs-x86_64/` and remove the original file:

  ```
  mv /home/aiphee/HoN/libs-x86_64/libstdc++.so.6 /home/aiphee/HoN/libs-x86_64/libstdc++.so.6.bak
  ```
- Create a symbolic link:

  ```
  ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 /home/aiphee/HoN/libs-x86_64/
  ```

Comment: Ok,  thanks. Game launched but there was some other error in fullscreen, ill post it here tomorrow.

Comment: Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me an upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers ;)

Comment: Yeah, sure sorry, i was in hurry :)

Comment: OK, your advide trully helped! Thanks, i would post a solution on HoN forums but they have some bug, when i try to post - white screen. Anyway, thanks :)

Comment: Gives me a segmentation fault. The developers are working on getting it up and running on the new ABI though so I guess I'll just have to wait

Answer (score 1):

A Heroes of Newerth developer posted this fix on the HoN reddit:

> The XML library we use has a new dependency on Ubuntu 15.04 which requires a newer version of the C++ standard library than we use.
>   The internal band-aid fix for this is to grab the libxml2.so.2 from a 12.04.5 and drop it into the HoN/libs-x86_64 directory and then HoN will be able to be launched.
>   Unfortunately we cannot redistribute that file ourselves but its worth trying as a work around for now. You may not have to go that far back (libxml2.so.2 from 14.10 might work fine, for example).

Link: [Link to post on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/HeroesofNewerth/comments/38skyd/thank_you_s2_frostburn_for_the_native_linux/csajrl5)

I had the same problem and fixed it this way. I think it's a bit cleaner than any of the other solutions that I found.